# Best way to execute asynchronous task on main thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I would like to know what is the best asynchronous way to execute a task on the main thread of a .NET application (in a ViewModel to be precise). Is  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke still valid nowadays or does it exist a better way to do that ?

Comment: I'm pretty certain you wouldn't want to introduce multithreading in a view model, maybe in controllers using the async ... await constructs.

Comment: Ok. Is there any problem doing some async/await in a ViewModel ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with threading in a view model (or async await for that matter).

Comment: I disagree. I cannot envisage a task a view model would be performing that would justify introducing multi-threading. If they are doing such a task chances are that task is in the wrong place.

Comment: @garryp How about loading data from the model? If my model is a WCF proxy, perhaps it has awaitable methods (actually have this one). Even if you abstract the `await` into a "Fire and forget" method, the VM is *still* effectively introducing threading. I think your view of the interactions involved is a bit simplistic, but I could easily be wrong :).

Comment: Its difficult without going into very specific examples, but I'd argue a model shouldn't be exposing that sort of information to the view model which is quite high level. I guess you're thinking of a model that is quite smart, whereas I favour models that are quite dumb with services and helpers encapsulating stuff like calls to WCF services.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BeginInvoke` is very low-level; there's always a better approach available.

In most cases, you can use `async`/`await` to kick off an asynchronous operation from the UI thread, and automagically return to the UI thread to display results. By default, the UI context is captured by `await` and used to resume the `async` method after the awaited operation completes. (I describe this in more detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)).

If you need to display progress reports from your UI, the best option is the `IProgress<T>`/`Progress<T>` types, which again do all the thread marshalling for you.

Finally, if you do need to update the UI with an unending sequence of data, the best option is to use Reactive Extensions and observe on a captured `SynchronizationContext`.

These options are from most common to least common. I'd guesstimate that 90% of use cases are covered with just `async`/`await`, 99% covered with `async`/`await` + `IProgress<T>`, and 100% covered with Rx. I have never run into a case where `BeginInvoke` is necessary. Or even beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to marshal actions onto the UI thread, yes, `BeginInvoke` is *still* the correct approach.

If you are already *on* the UI thread, but don't want your operation to block you can use `await`/`async`. Do note that this can *still* block your UI thread if the work being done isn't actually asynchronous and you are just wrapping it in a `Task.Run`.